Validate header's value using api gateway mapping template
I am currently working with GitLab webhook to trigger a Lambda function through AWS API Gateway, which will trigger a CI pipeline in another repository. My question is whether it is possible to validate the value of the X-Gitlab-Token in header at the mapping template level and if the token is incorrect just don't pass the request to Lambda. It should be done without invoking the any other Lambda function for validation
I'm looking for information is it even possible and if so what should be done for it (examples of mapping templates, etc.)

Amazon API Gateway doesn't validate header's value and probably you'd check API Gateway request validation but this will be checking only parameter existence in the request, rather than able to access the value.
For more information about request validation, see examined petType parameter in query string in "Set up basic request validation in API Gateway" document.
I would recommend a solution is checking X-Gitlab-Token in your very first Lambda function invocation in AWS Step Function or in the Lambda function, validate X-Gitlab-Token to execute or return an error in order to trigger other services such SNS to alert admin or users.
